# Password Validation on Dynamically Generated Form

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

So I'm just learning Angular and I have basic routing setup and a partial for setting up a basic page with a form (theoretically any form), and based on the controller I load it loads that form from a fields array in the controller.

One of those forms is a registration form where I want to verify that the passwords match.

So in the partial I have (a mode complicated version of) this

```
<input ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-model="field.model" mustEqual="fields.mustEqual">
```

I found a directive which does password comparison:

```
taskDivApp.directive('mustEqual', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) 
    {
      if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // watch own value and re-validate on change
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() 
      {
        validate();
      });

      // observe the other value and re-validate on change
      attrs.$observe('equals', function (val) 
      {
        validate();
      });

      var validate = function() 
      {
        // values
        var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
        var val2 = attrs.mustEqual;

        // set validity
        ngModel.$setValidity('equals', val1 === val2);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

So basically all I want to do is be able to load a literal string into ng-model from the controller so that I can pair up the model and the must equal, so the data for the form would look like:

```
$scope.fields = [
{
    'type':"Email",
    'placeholder':"Email Address",
    'req': true,
    'focus':true
},
{
    'type':"Password",
    'placeholder':"Password",
    'model': "password",
    'mustEqual': "passwordConf"
},
{
    'type':"Password",
    'placeholder':"Comfirm Password",
    'model':"passwordConf",
    'mustEqual': "password"
}
];
```

However what happens now is that the main password field gets bound to the "model" field of its index in the array and similar for passwordConf (ie inital values literally "password" and "passwordConf")

The fact that this isn't easy makes me think I have the wrong mindset - is this not a good way to do forms, should I just have them hard coded?
If this is okay then any ideas on how I could accomplish it would be appreciated!

Comment: First, you have a syntax error in the $scope.fileds assignment. There's a missing double quote for the model property value in the second list element. Second you are initializing the models with values "password" and "passwordConf" so yeah that is what will show up initally. The mustEqual stuff wont work because you need to pass it a reference to the other model in the $scope instead of the value of that variable - that, makes no sense.

Comment: That just came from trimming down the code for the post - it's fixed now. Right - I know that's why It's doing it now. What I want to do is generate something along the lines of " ng-model="password" " based on the value of field.model. So really it's more like field.modelName